# How to delete descriminator column from Asp.Net Identity tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I renamed the standard identity tables:

```
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        //...
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public DateTime? RegisteredDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastLoginDate { get; set; }
        //...
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
    }
```

and got this:

[image: Error One]

What do I need to do in `modelBuilder` to drop this column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Discriminator` column is used and required in Table-Per-Hierarchy inheritance scenarios.

Code First has to add a special column to distinguish between persistent classes. This isn’t a property of the persistent class in our object model; it’s used internally by EF Code First. By default, the column name is `Discriminator`, and its type is string. The values defaults to the persistent class names —in this case, `User`.
[More info](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)

**Update**

If you don't want that column, you can make `User` part of the model not `IdentityUser` for instance by adding a `DbSet<User>` to your context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
```